# Problem with generating allure report with cucumber and junit5

Tags: java, gradle, junit5, cucumber-jvm, allure

Based on site https://allurereport.org/docs/cucumberjvm/ I tried to configure allure reports
to project with junit5 and cucumber. Unfortunatelly report is not beeing generated.
Other reports (cucumber, junit) works correctly and are present.

This is my build.gradle.kts file:

```
plugins {
    id("java")
    id("io.qameta.allure") version "2.11.2"
}

apply(plugin = "io.qameta.allure")

group = "org.example"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

val allureVersion = "2.24.0"
val aspectJVersion = "1.9.22"

val agent: Configuration by configurations.creating {
    isCanBeConsumed = true
    isCanBeResolved = true
}

dependencies {
    agent("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:${aspectJVersion}")

    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.2"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.10.2")

    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.10.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.10.2")
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite:1.10.2")

    testImplementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9")
    testImplementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.5.3")

    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.25.3")
    
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:7.16.1")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.16.1")

    testImplementation("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4")

    testImplementation(platform("io.qameta.allure:allure-bom:$allureVersion"))
    testImplementation("io.qameta.allure:allure-cucumber7-jvm")
    testImplementation("io.qameta.allure:allure-junit-platform")
    
}

tasks.test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    jvmArgs = listOf(
            "-javaagent:${agent.singleFile}"
    )
}
```

I have also in

`/src/test/resources/`

allure.properties file with:

```
allure.results.directory=build/allure-results
```

I installed also:

```
npm install --save-dev allure-commandline
```

in project root directory .

At the end after executing command:

```
./gradlew clean build test
```

in intellij under windows

cucumber.html file is created but not allure report.
In directory

```
build\allure-results
```

only 2 files appears:

```
a437a757-9ea3-4eba-a064-12069f40c081-container.json
executor.json
```

Am I doing something incorrectly? Everything looks good.

**Edit:**

I tried to run exemplary solution ( https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-cucumber7-junit-platform-gradle-kts )
but it also ends without html file report in directory
build/allure-results , only few json files are created in this directory.

**Edit:**

It is possible to see result but results file have to be copied into directory:

`allure-results`

in a root directory.

After that report has to be generated, eg.:

`npx allure-commandline serve`

command has to be executed in root directory.

Final list of dependencies looks like:

```
val allureVersion = "2.26.0"
val aspectJVersion = "1.9.22"

dependencies {
    agent("org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:${aspectJVersion}")

    testImplementation(platform("org.junit:junit-bom:5.10.2"))
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter")
    testImplementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.9")
    testImplementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.5.3")
    testImplementation("org.assertj:assertj-core:3.25.3")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-junit-platform-engine:7.16.1")
    testImplementation("io.cucumber:cucumber-java:7.16.1")
    testImplementation("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-suite:1.10.2")
    testImplementation("org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4")
    testImplementation(platform("io.qameta.allure:allure-bom:$allureVersion"))
    testImplementation("io.qameta.allure:allure-cucumber7-jvm")
    testImplementation("io.qameta.allure:allure-junit-platform")
    testImplementation("io.qameta.allure:allure-junit5")

}
```

Comment: Presumably your dependencies aren't converging. The tutorial you're using uses the `cucumber-bom`, the `junit-bom` and the `allure-bom` to set all the verisons and then omits any other version numbers. The tutorial also links to a demo project which has configuration that looks rather different from yours https://github.com/allure-examples/allure-cucumber7-junit-platform-gradle-kts/blob/main/build.gradle.kts